# mesh function using matlab

Tags: matlab

coding below is to solve continuity equation decoupled from heat model
i need to produce the 3D plot of the ice thickness based on that coding
h_t=B+(D h_x)_x   D=Gam |h_x|^(n-1) h^(n+2)

```
n=3;
L=750000; % meters
dtyear=10;
Nx=30;
type=1;
Mt=ceil(25000/dtyear);
dx=(2*L)/Nx; x=-L:dx:L; % x grid
xmid=-L+dx/2:dx:L-dx/2; % midpt grid
xplot=linspace(-L,L,400); % for plotting analytical soln
iceconstants; %Gam=2*(rho*g)^n*A;
% constants related to grid
dt=dtyear*SperA;
R0=dt/(dx*dx); % presumed related to stability for continuity eqn
Tend=dt*Mt; % final time
t=0:dt:Tend;
% use either steady state analytical soln or zero as initial condition
ic=hexact;
%ic=zeros(1,Nx+1);
% allocate space for solutions
hh=zeros(Nx+1,Mt+1); % hh(j,l) with j for x and l for t
D=zeros(Nx+1,1); %column vector
hh(:,1)=ic'; %insert initial condition
%enforce boundary conditions at start
hh(1,:)=0; hh(Nx+1,:)=0;
D(1)=0; D(Nx+1)=0; % see steady bdry

for l=1:Mt
delh=(hh(2:Nx+1,l)-hh(1:Nx,l))/dx; % Nx by 1 column vector
hav=(hh(2:Nx+1,l)+hh(1:Nx,l))/2; % Nx by 1 col vect
Dmid=(Gam/(n+2))*hav.^(n+2).*abs(delh).^(n-1); % Nx by 1 col vect
F=Dmid.*(hh(2:Nx+1,l)-hh(1:Nx,l));
hh(2:Nx,l+1)=hh(2:Nx,l)+B*dt+R0*(F(2:Nx)-F(1:Nx-1));
end;

tplot=t(tt);
hplot=hh(:,tt);
subplot(3,1,3), mesh(tplot/SperA,x/1000,hplot), view(37.5,30); <--problem in this line
```

when i run this coding, i get this result

```
the result shows like this : 

??? Error using ==> mesh at 80
Data dimensions must agree.

Error in ==> iceA at 144
subplot(3,1,3), mesh(tplot/SperA,x/1000,hplot), view(37.5,30);
```

what does it mean by "Data dimensions must agree"??
i really appreciate it if u can help me:

Comment: this is too specialized and probably due to a sampling or indexing error of matrices/vectors. Try simulating the error, with fewer/random samples to understand the arguments and call of `mesh`.

Answer (score 0):

The error means that `tplot`, `x` and `hplot` should have the same dimensions, i.e. the output of `size()` on all three should be the same.

If they are generated independent from each other, take care to have the same size of grid points to the size of values for the mesh, i.e. when subsampling or indexing in matrices.

When forming functions analytically, like below, MATLAB will throw an error if `X` and `Y` have different sizes. If not, `Z` will have the same output size, as the grid point matrices `X` and `Y`.

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(-5:1:5);
Z = X.^2 + Y.^2;
mesh(X,Y,Z);
```